# Asp.Net Mvc HtmlHelper testing VeiwContext.Writer.WriteLine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, moq, html-helper, xunit.net

I have a HtmlHelper which is used to output some accordion style functionality. This helper is going to be used extensively throughout the site.

The code used to create this functionality makes extensive use of `TagBuilder` and of course we are outputting the html using:

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(someTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
```

We have a few helpers which use this pattern and it's working great.

All good so far - it does exactly what I want. However - testing this is proving to be a nightmare. how do i test `htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine` ?

we're using xUnit and Moq if it matters

Comment: One of the samples I could find is here: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/09/10/38638/ but that seems to assume a standard extension of the HtmlHelper using `public static MvcHtmlString...` in which the method return something like `return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));`. what is your html helper method actualy returning?

Comment: we are using the same pattern used by the MvcForm stuff. So it returns an Accordian : IDisposable  class.

Comment: I see. Could you not do something similar in your test as the guy in the link I posted. In your case your return value is an instance of the Accordion class which you could then inspect and assert accordingly?

Comment: no because the accordian is only really responsible for shoving out the end tag at the end of the using block... i need to see what the WriteLine call is outputting.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realise. I assumed the line was written to the object you return which would have been testable. Maybe you can inject a custom ViewContext you can interogate after the method has executed to validate what was written to it? Or you need to refactor your code to ensure each element is testable. Sorry I wasn't able to help out much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var viewContext = new ViewContext();
var viewContextWriter = new Mock<TextWriter>();
var text = string.Empty;
viewContextWriter.Setup(m => m.WriteLine(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((string s) => text += s);
viewContext.Writer = viewContextWriter.Object;
var html = new HtmlHelper(viewContext, new FakeViewDataContainer());

private class FakeViewDataContainer : IViewDataContainer
{
    private ViewDataDictionary _viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData
    {
        get { return _viewData; }
        set { _viewData = value; }
    }
}
```

When you assert, whatever is written out to Writer.WriteLine will be in the text method's `text` variable.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to test and validate html helpers.

Validation is a another example.

Try the following:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var context = new ViewContext();
context.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(_testModel);
context.Writer = new StringWriter(sb);
var page = new ViewPage<TestModel>();
var helper = new HtmlHelper<TestModel>(context, page);

//Do your stuff here to exercise your helper

//Following example contains two helpers that are being tested
//A MyCustomBeginForm Helper and a OtherCoolHelperIMade Helper
using(helper.MyCustomBeginForm("secretSauce"))
{
   helper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(helper.OtherCoolHelperIMade("bigMacSauce"));
}
//End Example

//Get the results of all helpers
var result = sb.ToString();

//Asserts and string tests here for emitted HTML
Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(result);
```